# Why is "shadow-cljs cljs-repl app" still working while cider-jack-in-cljs is retrieving an error?

Tags: java, clojurescript, cider, sdkman, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command `cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, choosing `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the building option.

It used to work and `cider-jack-in-cljs` still works if I check out some previous commits from last week. There was a big merge of a huge branch into the main branch. **To make it work is even necessary to tweak the java version**.

Currently, I have two java versions. The new main branch uses the `11.0.16-amzn` and last week main branch uses `8.0.342-amzn`:

```bash
Pedros-MacBook-Air:balance pedro$ sdk use java 
11.0.16-amzn  8.0.342-amzn
```

Unfortunately, now, in the latest current main branch, `cider-jack-in-cljs` does not work anymore. The command returns this error message:

```clj
[nREPL] Starting server via /opt/homebrew/bin/shadow-cljs -d nrepl/nrepl:0.9.0 -d cider/cider-nrepl:0.28.5 -d refactor-nrepl/refactor-nrepl:3.5.5 -d cider/piggieback:0.5.2 server
error in process sentinel: nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: shadow-cljs - config: /Users/pedro/projects/balance/shadow-cljs.edn
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error macroexpanding at (user.clj:1:1).
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7665)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:368)
    at clojure.lang.RT.maybeLoadResourceScript(RT.java:364)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:486)
    at clojure.lang.RT.init(RT.java:467)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForNameNonLoading(RT.java:2222)
    at cljs.externs$loading__6706__auto____1271.invoke(externs.clj:9)
    at cljs.externs__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.externs__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at cljs.env$loading__6706__auto____851.invoke(env.cljc:9)
    at cljs.env__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.env__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1523)
    at cljs.analyzer$loading__6706__auto____2000.invoke(analyzer.cljc:9)
    at cljs.analyzer__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.analyzer__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:930)
    at cljs.compiler$loading__6706__auto____1998.invoke(compiler.cljc:9)
    at cljs.compiler__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.compiler__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:2088)
    at cljs.repl$loading__6706__auto____1381.invoke(repl.cljc:9)
    at cljs.repl__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.repl__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at alan.user$eval138$loading__6789__auto____139.invoke(user.clj:1)
    at alan.user$eval138.invokeStatic(user.clj:1)
    at alan.user$eval138.invoke(user.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7194)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7183)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7653)
    ... 6 more

error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: shadow-cljs - config: /Users/pedro/projects/balance/shadow-cljs.edn
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error macroexpanding at (user.clj:1:1).
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7665)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:381)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:368)
    at clojure.lang.RT.maybeLoadResourceScript(RT.java:364)
    at clojure.lang.RT.doInit(RT.java:486)
    at clojure.lang.RT.init(RT.java:467)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilerOptions has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForNameNonLoading(RT.java:2222)
    at cljs.externs$loading__6706__auto____1271.invoke(externs.clj:9)
    at cljs.externs__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.externs__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at cljs.env$loading__6706__auto____851.invoke(env.cljc:9)
    at cljs.env__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.env__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1523)
    at cljs.analyzer$loading__6706__auto____2000.invoke(analyzer.cljc:9)
    at cljs.analyzer__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.analyzer__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:930)
    at cljs.compiler$loading__6706__auto____1998.invoke(compiler.cljc:9)
    at cljs.compiler__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.compiler__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:2088)
    at cljs.repl$loading__6706__auto____1381.invoke(repl.cljc:9)
    at cljs.repl__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at cljs.repl__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2209)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2218)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2237)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:449)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:424)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__6908.invoke(core.clj:6161)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:6160)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:6144)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invokeStatic(core.clj:5933)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5928)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__6850.invoke(core.clj:5975)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.invokeStatic(core.clj:5974)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5953)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.invokeStatic(core.clj:6016)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:6000)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:669)
    at clojure.core$require.invokeStatic(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:6038)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at alan.user$eval138$loading__6789__auto____139.invoke(user.clj:1)
    at alan.user$eval138.invokeStatic(user.clj:1)
    at alan.user$eval138.invoke(user.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7194)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7183)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7653)
    ... 6 more
```

At the same time, it is possible to build the main branch locally after running on the terminal the following:

```bash
shadow-cljs cljs-repl app
```

My hypothesis (that could be wrong) is that the terminal is using the right java version. But, Emacs is not!

I would rather use the CIDER environment. Why is CIDER not working while the terminal is working?

Since I have already used `sdkman` on terminal to tweak the Java version, why is Emacs not using the proper version (apparently, related to my hypothesis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My hypothesis (that could be wrong) is that the terminal is using the right java version. But, Emacs is not!

This is correct. Latest versions of shadow-cljs require Java11+ to be used.

The error you get is from using a newer shadow-cljs version with an old java version.

No clue how you make emacs use the newer version though.